# How can I test if a value is a string or an int?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding Variable Type in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456336/finding-variable-type-in-javascript)

How can I test if a value is a string or an int? Something like...

X = ?

if X is an Int {}

if X is a String {}

Thanks!

Comment: We could probabably help better if you described what problem you're really trying to solve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof) operator:

```
var x = 1;
console.log(typeof x);
x = 'asdf';
console.log(typeof x);
```

Prints:

```
number
string
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that favors `typeof`, but defaults to `Object.prototype.toString` *(which is much slower)* when needed.

This way some of those unexpected values you'll get from `new String('x')` or `null` or `/regex/` (in Chrome) are covered.

```
var type = (function () {
    var toString = Object.prototype.toString,
        typeof_res = {
            'undefined': 'undefined',
            'string': 'string',
            'number': 'number',
            'boolean': 'boolean',
            'function': 'function'
        },
        tostring_res = {
            '[object Array]': 'array',
            '[object Arguments]': 'arguments',
            '[object Function]': 'function',
            '[object RegExp]': 'regexp',
            '[object Date]': 'date',
            '[object Null]': 'null',
            '[object Error]': 'error',
            '[object Math]': 'math',
            '[object JSON]': 'json',
            '[object Number]': 'number',
            '[object String]': 'string',
            '[object Boolean]': 'boolean',
            '[object Undefined]': 'undefined'
        };
    return function type(x) {
        var the_type = typeof_res[typeof x];
        return the_type && (the_type !== 'function' || (x.apply && x.call)) ?
            the_type :
            tostring_res[toString.call(x)] || (x ? 'object' : 'null');
    };
})();
```

---

```
type( new String('test') ); // string
type( function(){} );       // function
type( null );               // null
type( /regex/ );            // regexp
```

---

**EDIT:** *I had just done a rewrite, and removed a key part of the function. Fixed.*

Or for a more compact version:

```
var type = (function() {
    var i, lc, toString = Object.prototype.toString,
        typeof_res = {},
        tostring_res = {},
        types = 'Undefined,String,Number,Boolean,Function,Array,Arguments,RegExp,Date,Null,Error,Math,JSON'.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        lc = types[i].toLowerCase();
        if (i < 5) typeof_res[lc] = lc;
        tostring_res['[object ' + types[i] + ']'] = lc;
    }

    return function type(x) {
        var the_type = typeof_res[typeof x];
        return the_type && (the_type !== 'function' || (x.apply && x.call)) ? 
            the_type : 
            tostring_res[toString.call(x)] || (x ? 'object' : 'null');
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof) does the trick *most* of the time. But if your `Number` or `String` is not a primitive, it will return `'object'`. Generally, that is not what you want.

```
var str = new String('Hello');
typeof str; // 'object'
```

`typeof` also says that `null` is an `'object'` and in WebKit, a regex is a `'function'`. I think the main advantage of `typeof` is to check for a variable without throwing a `ReferenceError`.

You can check a variable's `constructor` property too, or use `variable instanceof String`. However, both of these don't work in a multiple `window` environment when using cross `window` code.

The other *guaranteed* way of determining the type is with...

```
var getType = function(variable) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(variable).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase();
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xug86/).

Comment: I remember you explaining this to me just a month or so ago.

Comment: `typeof str; // 'number'` ? That one must be from IE5. ;)

Answer (score 0):

use JavaScript built in `typeof` function

```
var s = "string",
    n = 1; // number

if(typeof s == 'string'){
  //do stuff for string
}


if(typeof n == 'number'){
  //do stuff for number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already talked about the `typeof` operator, and use of `Object.prototype.toString`, but if you want to specifically test for an int as compared to any sort of number then you can do some variation of this:

```
function isInt(n) {
   return typeof n === "number" && n === Math.floor(n);
}
```

(Insert all the `Object.prototype.toString` stuff if desired.)