# How does Javascript know what type a variable is?

Tags: javascript, types

I don't know why I never asked myself that questioned the last years before, but suddenly I could not find any answer for myself or with google.

Javascript is known to have no types for variables. A really nice thing.
But somehow it must determine the type and work with it.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2.0;
var c = 'c';
var d = "Hello World!";
```

So what we have is an Integer, Double/Float, Character, String (which may be teared down as char*)

I know that JS works with a runtime interpreter, but thinking of that the logic and "type" must be implemented in any way..

So how does a Javascript Interpreter recognize and internally handle the variables?
In my imagination, assuming I would write C++, I would think of a sort of template and container and a bit of a logic that overloads operators and try to check, what it really is. But that's not thought to the end.

Share your knowledge with me please :-)

Comment: Well, variables are not typed, but values are. The specification only describes how certain mechanisms in the language work, it does not define an implementation. Often you find expression like *"If Type(x) is String..."*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding Variable Type in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456336/finding-variable-type-in-javascript)

Comment: again.. I did not ask how to determine the type in a js program during runtime.

Comment: This is not a real question. Look into the source code if you want to know about the internal structures.

Comment: In that case I would revise my vote from duplicate to non-constructive. How an interpreter tracks variables and their metadata is an implementation detail and surely varies between different implementations.

Comment: @veredesmarald that is absolutely correct - why you like to set this question as non-constructive I can not understand. I made it clear for a given interpreter and situation - I pointed exactly out what I would like to know. As you can see there were other users that were able to give a useful and correct answer - if you don't like this question feel again free to do so - but be yourself constructive. Thank you for telling me your point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript sets the variable type based on the value assignment. For example when JavaScript encounters the following code it knows that `myVariable` should be of type number:

```
var myVariable = 10;
```

Similarly, JavaScript will detect in the following example that the variable type is string:

```
var myVariable = "Hello World!";
```

JavaScript is also much more flexible than many other programming languages. With languages such as Java a variable must be declared to be a particular type when it is created and once created, the type cannot be changed. This is referred to as **[strong typing](http://timkadlec.com/2008/04/an-objective-look-at-javascript-2-0-strong-typing/)**. JavaScript, on the other hand, allows the type of a variable to be changed at any time simply by assigning a value of a different type (better known as **[loose typing](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/03/understanding-loose-typing-in.html)**).

The following example is perfectly valid use of a variable in JavaScript. At creation time, the variable is clearly of type number. A later assignment of a string to this variable changes the type from number to string.

```
var myVariable = 10;
myVariable = "This is now a string type variable";
```

The **variable’s data type is the JavaScript scripting engine’s interpretation** of the type of data that variable is currently holding. A string variable holds a string; a number variable holds a number value, and so on. However, unlike many other languages, in JavaScript, the same variable can hold different types of data, all within the same application. This is a concept known by the terms loose typing and dynamic typing, both of which mean that a JavaScript variable can hold different data types at different times depending on context.

**Complete article here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/JavaScript_Variable_Types**

**Another Article Which may help you: http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/learning-javascript/javascript-datatypes-variables.html**

**Useful links:**

**[ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)**

**[ECMAScript BNF Grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1153976512034/ecmascriptA3.g)**

**[JAVAScript BNF Gramar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1206736738015/JavaScript.g)**

Comment: Combining the answer of @James Allardice and yours, do I understand it right that its bnf (backus naur form) and a grammar that assigns the right type?

Comment: @Stefan I've added some useful links in the end of my answer in which you might be interested...

Answer (score 1):

The only useful line I can find in the [ES5 spec](http://es5.github.com/#x8) is this:

> Within this specification, the notation “Type(x)” is used as shorthand for “the type of x” where “type” refers to the ECMAScript language and specification types defined in this clause.

I *assume* that when the runtime needs to perform an operation that needs to know the type of some value, it will check that value against the [grammar defined in the spec](http://es5.github.com/#A.1) for each type, until it finds a match.

For example, the grammer for a boolean literal is as follows:

> *BooleanLiteral* ::
>
> ```
>   true 
>   false
> ```

If the value is exactly `true` or exactly `false` (e.g. with no quotes) then that value is of type boolean.

Comment: Combining the answer of @AlphaMale and yours, do I understand it right that its bnf (backus naur form) and a grammar that assigns the right type?

Comment: Well the grammar defines the types, the runtime should be able to use that grammar to determine the type of the value.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript itself does have types, and internally, each assignment receives an appropriate type. In your example `var foo = 2.0;` the type will be `float`. The programmer needn't worry about that too much (at first) because JS is *loosly typed* (!== type-free). 
That means that if I were to compare a numeric string to a float, the engine will coerce the string to a number so that the comparison can be preformed.

The main difference between loose typed and strong typed languages is not type coercion, though. It's quite common in C(++) to cast to the type you need, and in some cases values are automatically converted to the correct type (`2/2.0 == 2.0/2.0 == 1.0` ==> int is converted to float, implicitly). The main difference between loosly typed and strong typed languages is that you declare a variable with a distinct type:

```
int i = 0;//ok
//Later:
i = 'a';//<-- cannot assign char to int
```

whereas JS allows you to do:

```
var i = 1;//int
i = 1.123;//float
i = 'c';//char, or even strings
i = new Date();//objects
```

But, as functions/keywords like `typeof`, `instanceof`, `parseFloat`, `parseInt`,`toString`... suggest: there are types, they're just a tad more flexible. And variables aren't restricted to a single type.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to imagine an implementation is that all values are kept in objects and that all variables are pointers... in C++:

```
struct Value
{
    int type;
    Value(int type) : type(type) { }
    virtual ~Value() { }

    virtual std::string toString() = 0;
};

struct String : Value
{
    std::string x;
    String(const std::string& x) : Value(STRING_TYPE), x(x) { }
    virtual std::string toString()
    {
        return x;
    }
};

struct Number : Value
{
    double x;
    Number(double x) : Value(NUMBER_TYPE), x(x) { }
    ...
};

struct Object : Value
{
    // NOTE: A javascript object is stored as a map from property
    //       names to Value*, not Value. The key is a string but
    //       the value can be anything
    std::map<std::string, Value *> x;
    Object() : Value(OBJECT_TYPE), x(x) { }
    ...
};
```

For example whenever an operation has to be performed (e.g. `a+b`) you need to check the types of the objects pointed by the variables to decide what to do.

Note that this is an ultra-simplistic explanation... javascript today is much more sophisticated and optimized than this, but you should be able to get a rough picture.