# Cant deploy function to Firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, function, google-cloud-functions

I'm following the video of Doug on youtube to change a message with functions, I'm doing it in javascript, I have installed flow lenguage script since I had an error about `'types' can only be applied to ts files` , now, that error is gone, but when I try to deploy my function I get this error message.

[image]

This is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

    exports.createdMessage = functions.database.ref('/users/messages/{messageId}').onCreate((snapshot,context)=>{

            const messageID = context.params.messageId;
            console.log('Message ${messageID}');

            const messageData = snapshot.val();
            const message = placeEmoticon(messageData.message);


            return snapshot.ref.update({message:message});

    });

    function placeEmoticon(message : string): string {

        return message.replace(/\bcar\b/g,'');

    }
```

Comment: there is no ":" in javascript, it should be `function placeEmoticon(message){return message.replace(/\bcar\b/g,'');}`

Comment: hi, thanks peter, but how javascript knows that parameter is a string type ?

Comment: this `function placeEmoticon(message : string): string {

        return message.replace(/\bcar\b/g,'');

    }` is in typescript https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364614/how-does-javascript-know-what-type-a-variable-is

Comment: Thanks so much, can you post this as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: I have this last error placeEmoticon is not defined
    at exports.createdMessage.functions.database.ref.onCreate

Comment: I just fixed it, thanks so much peter !

Comment: no problem goodluck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
function placeEmoticon(message : string): string {

    return message.replace(/\bcar\b/g,'');

}
```

This is written in typescript where you can specify the return type and the type of the parameters. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

into this:

```
function placeEmoticon(message) {

    return message.replace(/\bcar\b/g,'');

}
```

Since you are using javascript.