# javascript function error while adding blank functions

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to javascript. following is my `.js`-file which I am importing in my `html` file-

```
function primaerror(strmessage) 
{
alert(strmessage);
return null;
}
function showdiagnosis(string pid){}
function showimages(){}
function showimage(){}
```

I get :

```
 Error  = "Expected ')'. Line:5 Char:31"
```

Please help me where the error could be?

Thanks

Comment: JavaScript is weakly typed language. Also if you come from Java I'd suggest you start with JavaScript from scratch because if you follow Java patterns when you get to `this` the world will cease to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Javascript` doesn't have the `keyword` `string` in first place.

You are not supposed to give datatypes for variables, you may not even use `var` keyword before formal parameters.

`Javascript` interpreter can understand the type of the value a variable pointing. Since, variables doesn't have any types in particular and can be messed up any way, hence it is called `weakly typed language`.

Changing `function showdiagnosis(string pid){}` to

```
         `function showdiagnosis(pid){}`
```

If you need you can use `typeof` keyword to know the type value passed through pid.

For example:

```
          function showDiagnosis(pid){

              if(typeof pid=='string')
              //................

          }
```

This link is valuable and you may want to check it:

[Finding variable type in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456336/finding-variable-type-in-javascript)

[Check if a variable is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string)

[Check whether variable is number or string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303646/check-whether-variable-is-number-or-string-in-javascript)

And use proper naming conventions for function names, variables. In general, `Javascript` community follows `showDiagnosis(pid)` for your case. Start with small letter and capitalize every first letter of distinct words in the name so that it makes some sense for readers and increases readability.

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language, it doesn't need (and don't allow) type declaration for function parameters, so you should remove `string` from `function showdiagnosis(string pid){}`.

```
function primaerror(strmessage) 
{
alert(strmessage);
return null;
}
function showdiagnosis(pid){}
function showimages(){}
function showimage(){}
```

You may want to check the type of the parameter manually if you need to.

See also: [Set type for function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407622/set-type-for-function-parameters)