# using typeof to check primitive types javascript

Tags: javascript, typeof

Hi I want to check primitive types using javascripfor example

```
var x //some kind of input is needed like prompt?
if x is a string then alert typeof x is a string

else if x is a boolean alert typeof  x  is a boolean

else 
return alert x is a number
```

I dont know how to use  typeof to check this because i just started learning javascript. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't know how an operator works, **read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)**. Then ask for clarification if you didn't understand everything.

Comment: Given that you've explicitly used the string `typeof` of in your pseudo code, where are you stuck? Hint: `typeof` would be useful for the first part. Incidentally: *any* input taken from a user via the `prompt()` is going to be a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Variable Type in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4456336/218196)

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof "John"                 // Returns string 
typeof 3.14                   // Returns number
typeof false                  // Returns boolean
typeof [1,2,3,4]              // Returns object
typeof {name:'John', age:34}  // Returns object
```

Here's some [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp)

Comment: FWIW, Array is not a data type in JS (the article make it looks like it is).

Comment: @FelixKling I'm sorry I don't know what FWIW means but thank you anyways. Although it seems to return object, doesn't it?

Comment: FWIW means "for what it's worth". Yes it returns "object" which is correct, but the article is titled "data types" and lists Array, even though it's not a data type. I just wanted to point out this minor discrepancy.

Comment: @FelixKling OIC...hehe