# Null check for a value is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to null check in one input field and pop up a required message in another input field. To achieve this function i have used the below Javascript code.

```
$(document).on('change', '.address',function () {


  if ($(this).val() == null ) {
    $('#cutomer_id').prop('required',true);
  }
});
```

but this is not working as expected. but when i try the opposite if ($(this).val() != null ) its fire the required messege.

Comment: Because it's not actually null? Print it and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456336/finding-variable-type-in-javascript.

Comment: console.log($(this).val()) is the absolute first thing you should do.

Comment: `null` and empty string are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's because [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) is an object, but value of  element is a string

What you need is check against an empty string:

```
if (this.value.trim() == "")
{
  $('#cutomer_id').prop('required',true);
}
```

The `trim()` added to remove trailing spaces.

P.S.
please avoid unnecessary use of jquery or any other bloatware, `$(this).val()` is absolutely ridiculously unnecessary